# Файл не проходит проверку на "файловость"

Tags: python-3.x, файлы, файловая-система

Ищу все файлы в директории и хеширую их. Но если директория не cwd, файлы не проходят проверку os.path.isfile

```
import os
import hashlib

BUF_SIZE = 65536
dir = "D:\\_itra\\task2\\test1"

for file in os.listdir(dir) :
    if os.path.isfile(os.path.abspath(file)) :
        # print(os.path.abspath(file))
        with open(os.path.abspath(file), 'rb') as f:
            data = f.read(BUF_SIZE)
            sha3 = hashlib.sha3_256()
            sha3.update(data)
            print(file, sha3.hexdigest())
```

если `dir = os.getcwd()`, то те же файлы нормально проверяются и хешируются.

Comment: Потому что переменная `file` содержит только имя файла, а не полный путь к нему

Comment: для этого я пишу `os.path.abspath(file)`

Comment: ...и получается несуществующий путь, потому что `file` содержит только имя файла и функция abspath не имеет никакой информации о том, в какой папке на самом деле лежит этот файл. Нужно делать `os.path.join(dir, file)` чтобы к имени файла добавить папку из переменной `dir`